# RedShift tabel rows are getting doubled after updation using another table(KEY distribution style)

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am new to `Redshift` and working on huge datasets. Distribution style of table is `KEY` and when adding an empty new column to that table and update it with another table by using `JOIN`. I could see that table rows are getting doubled from `svv_table_info` table and consuming too much space.

I already tried `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`.

Comment: please provide your ddl/sql in your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE ca_ger.cln_trans_base
(
    store_code VARCHAR(25),
    year_week varchar(25),    division VARCHAR(25) encode lzo,
    market_share_code VARCHAR(25) encode bytedict,
    pon VARCHAR(25) encode lzo,  
    osp_price REAL encode bytedict)
    diststyle key
    distkey(store_code)
    sortkey(store_code,year_week);
COMMIT;

Comment: Thanks but please 1) update your question with that (in a code block) and 2) also update your question with the sql you are using to add a columns and the sql you are using to populate that new column.

Comment: please find new question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893344/redshift-tabel-rows-are-getting-doubled-after-updation-using-another-table  . thanks in advance @JonScott

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RedShift table rows are duplicated after updating using another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893344/redshift-table-rows-are-duplicated-after-updating-using-another-table)