# RedShift table rows are duplicated after updating using another table

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-update, amazon-redshift

**Main Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE ca_ger.cln_trans_base (
  store_code VARCHAR(25),
  year_week varchar(25),
  division VARCHAR(25) encode lzo,
  market_share_code VARCHAR(25) encode bytedict,
  pon   VARCHAR(25) encode lzo,
  osp_price REAL encode bytedict
)
diststyle key distkey(store_code)
sortkey(store_code,year_week); 

COMMIT;
```

**Second table:**

```
CREATE TABLE ca_ger.divisions(
  store_code VARCHAR(25),
  year_week varchar(25),
  division VARCHAR(25) encode lzo
)
diststyle key distkey(store_code)
sortkey(store_code,year_week); 

COMMIT; 

alter table ca_ger.cln_Trans_base
add column division(varchar 25);
```

**Join clause:**

```
update ca_ger.cln_trans_base 
 set division=b.division 
from ca_Ger.cln_trans_base a 
  join divisions b on a.year_week=b.year_week;
```

After this, I ran `vacuum` and `analyze`. After this, I checked stats table and rows are doubled.

Comment: Are you saying that a `count(*)` returns a different value before and after the `update`?

Comment: You should **not** repeat the table to be updated in the FROM clause of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope, count(*) return the same number of row count but whenever i query from redshift, it is scanning double the number of row blocks. and also, can you please provide sample query without including target table in FROM clause

Comment: You need a `vacuum full` to cleanup the old rows.

Comment: if you update multiple times, do the stats get worse? - can you try "vacuum tablename to 100 percent". what happens if you add more data? more doubling?

Comment: yes, stats getting increased by the number of actual rows every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Amazon Redshift,

> Update=DELETE+INSERT

Hence your rows size is doubled. As you might be updating all the rows.

After every Update or on scheduled basis, you should be doing `full Vaccum` as suggested in one of comment.

```
VACUUM FULL cln_trans_base
```

It will reduce the size to half.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: It worked with the above solution and this solution. happy to see this on monday morning. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Extending @a_horse's suggestion, the UPDATE statement should not repeat the table being updated. Instead, use:

```
UPDATE ca_ger.cln_trans_base a
SET division = b.division 
FROM divisions b
WHERE a.year_week = b.year_week;
```

See: [PostgreSQL UPDATE Join with A Practical Example](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/)